# Using ASP.NET Entity Data for Complex Relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework

I have a complex relationship in my Database.

```
Packages (packageID, package_name , .... )
VariantPackage (packageID, variantID)
Variant (variantID, variant_name, .... )
ProductVariant (variantID, productID)
Product (productID, product_name, .... )
```

(I take it you can assume the ID fields are Primary or Foreign respectively?)

The entity framework has elegantly picked up on this because if do this:

```
Package newPackage = new Package()
{
 packageID = Guid.NewGuid()
 etc . . .
};

Variant newVariant = new Variant()
{
 variantID = Guid.NewGuid()
 etc . . .
};
```

I get the option when doing this line below to add the variant to that package

```
newPackage.Variant.AddObject(newVariant);
_db.Package.AddObject(newPackage);
_db.SaveChanges();
```

Now when I SaveChanges will that in those 2 lines, create entries in all 3 tables? If I have set up the model correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use CodeFirst Entity Framework now:

```
public abstract class DbEntity
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGenerated.Identity)]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class Package : DbEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Variant> Variants { get; set; }
}

public class Variant : DbEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product : DbEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then when this is created, it should then create the appropriate tables and constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Each table should have one insert method(call an addobject for a table). and arrange the call of insert methods that tables are related are very important.
use this code for insert Variant to DB:

```
public void InsertVariant(Variant entry)
{
            var t = _db.Variant.CreateObject();
            t.variant_name = entry.variant_name;
// and copy all field ...
// then
            _db.Variant.AddObject(t);
            _db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: I understand that, but are you saying, instead of doing it together in one go, you should do it seperately even though the entity frameworks main job is to provide support for relational databasing